# Homescreen.js not displaying in localhost/home needed output in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm having problems with displaying the rooms of my hotel reservation website. I cant find the solution. Please help me. I've spent 3 hours trying to find solutions

My Homescreen.js

```js
import React ,{useState, useEffect, } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';


function Homescreen(){

  let [ rooms, setrooms ] = useState([])
  const [loading, setloading] = useState()
  const [error, seterror] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getResults() {
      setloading(true)
      const data = (await axios('/api/rooms/getallrooms')).data;
      setrooms(data)
      setloading(false)
      seterror(true)
      setloading(false)
    };
    getResults()
  
  },[])
  

  return (
    <div>
        {loading? (<h1>loading...</h1>) :error ? (<h1>Error</h1>) :(rooms.map(room=>{

            return <h1>{room.name}</h1>

        }))}
       
    </div>
  )
}

export default Homescreen
```

Output I'm getting
[image: Output I'm getting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `error` to `true` in all cases, try to change your code to (using a `try catch` to detect errors):

```
function Homescreen() {
    let [rooms, setrooms] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
    const [error, seterror] = useState(false);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      async function getResults() {
        try {
          seterror(false);
          setloading(true);
          const data = (await axios('/api/rooms/getallrooms')).data;
          setrooms(data);
          setloading(false);
        } catch (e) {
          seterror(true);
          setloading(false);
        }
      }
      getResults();
    }, []);
  
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, im not used v6. Your such a timesaver :)